# moving an L-shaped piece on a grid

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic, position

i'm trying to code a small grid game, but i'm having trouble with coding piece movements.

I have a small 4x4 rgb pixels grid, initialized as np.zeros(4,4,3), full black. An update method to refresh objects position and free cells, a reset method, and a simple show function that uses cv2 to show the grid from a pixel matrix.

```
class Grid():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cells = np.zeros((SIZE, SIZE, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        self.free_cells = []

    def update(self, c, l):
        self.reset()  #clear cells and free cells list

        self.cells[c.x][c.y] = COIN_COL  #set coin position

        for i in range(len(l.coords)):   #set L posiion
                self.cells[l.coords[i][0]][l.coords[i][1]] = L_COL

        for i in range(len(self.cells)):  #calculate free cells
            for j in range(len(self.cells)):
                if np.amax(self.cells[i][j]) == 0:
                    self.free_cells.append((i, j))

    def reset(self):
        self.cells = np.zeros((SIZE, SIZE, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        self.free_cells = []

    def show(self):
        img = Image.fromarray(self.cells, "RGB")
        img = img.resize((200,200))

        cv2.imshow('img', np.array(img))
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

on the grid there are 2 pieces, an L-shaped one 3x2, and a coin 1x1.
they both have colors and coordinates

```
SIZE = 4
COIN_COL = (255,255,255)
L_COL = (0,0,255)
C_COORDS = np.array((0,0), dtype=np.uint8)  #coin starting position
L_COORDS = np.array(((1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(3,2)), dtype=np.uint8) #L starting position

class Coin():
    def __init__(self, coords):
        self.x = coords[0]
        self.y = coords[1]

class LShape():
    def __init__(self, coords):
        self.coords = coords
```

each piece can rotate, translate and move whenever he wants as long as it stays inside the grid, and does not overlap with other pieces.

moving the coin is straightforward: check empty cells, choose one, update coin coordinates, update grid.

Moving the L, doesn't look that simple. How can i check every possible legal move of such a piece? (there could be more than 1 coin on the grid). i started by calculating the empty cells, so that i have a layout of the free space, and i'm trying to come up with an algorithm to highlight legal moves by first removing isolated free cells (1x1), than removing isolated couples (2x1), and so on, but i got stuck halfway through.

I was also thinking about making a list of every possible position on an empty grid, and removing positions from the list if they require an occupied cell, but that doesn't seems elegant nor optimal.

Any idea on how to approach the problem?

Comment: Why don't you first try asking with tag [tag:language-agnostic] which will answer **how**, then writing the code yourself. Then if you have problems with that you can ask a **what** question with tag [tag:python-3].

Comment: thanks for the advice, i wanted to show a bit of code to better address the problem, but i think you're right

Comment: Not an answer, but an idea that I am curious to know if someone answering this knows this also. Normally I like to look for [Hamiltonian Cycles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HamiltonianCycle.html) in answers, but this probably has dead ends branching off  the cycle(s). As I didn't know the name of this graph searched and found [sinkless (finite) digraph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787076/is-there-a-classification-for-this-kind-of-graph/1787107#1787107). So I am wondering if my assumption is right and also if I found the right name.

Comment: `that doesn't seems elegant nor optimal.` Depends upon when the calculation is done. If the data is precomputed and stored then you have simplified the problem. Then if you find a way to store the data such that it can be easily searched you have simplified the problem again. Now if you connect all of the valid positions based on the potion of a coin you get a graph. Now if you know how to move in the graph from one position to the next you have converted the problem into just moves on the graph which give you a O(1) solution. That of course is if all of my ideas hold.